# How to set table name for @ElementCollection in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am using

```
public class UserTask extends BaseObject implements Serializable {
    
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class) 
    private List<String> userTaskMessage = new ArrayList<>();
   
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

Hibernate generate table, which name is `usertask_usertaskmessage`.

How do I set my name? For example `my_table_example`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use annotation  @CollectionTable(name="your_table_name")

Answer (score 37):

**JPA:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICES")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID") 
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "SERVICE_LINKED_CODES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICE_ID"))
    @Column(name = "CODE") 
    private List<String> linkedCodes;

}
```

**Schema in DB:**

```
CREATE TABLE SERVICES { ID BIGINT };
CREATE TABLE SERVICE_LINKED_CODES { SERVICE_ID BIGINT, CODE VARCHAR(255) };
```